# Iptables redirect to localhost?

Tags: networking, iptables

Suppose I have a network with a server routing all connections from inside the network to the Internet. How can I set up iptables so that instead of routing incoming connections to the Internet, it instead routes them to localhost port 8080. All help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that with simple redirection (destination IP address NAT) you will lose the original destination IP address. Do you want to setup a transparent HTTP proxy or should it process other protocols than HTTP too?

Comment: It doesn't matter if its transparent or not

Comment: Redirecting all the traffic to a proxy **is** a base for transparent proxy :)

Comment: Here's another answer that really helped me out:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111433/iptables-redirect-outside-requests-to-127-0-0-1/112232

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: don't use bold ....

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet but I suspect what I've been missing is the ip forwarding command. And next time, please use code blocks, not bold.

Comment: @AlexAntonov please use code blocks. Select your text in edit mode and click the brackets icon.

Comment: @ZoveGames, sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Is the ip_forward setting needed at all?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda, yes, this parameter is required, because traffic won't be forwarded between interfaces without it.

Comment: @AlexAntonov I don't think this is forwarding between interfaces. Did you actually try with ip_forward=0?

Comment: I experimented with this. The ip_forward sysctl is not necessary. However the route_localnet option [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112232/5587) is. I see now this is exactly what Juan Cespedes' [answer](http://superuser.com/a/807612/15896) states.

Comment: This advice is not quite all one needs they must also do something like this: `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet = 1` in their sysctl settings. You should update your post.

Comment: doesnt work . however this works sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1

Answer (score 46):

that can be done with `iptables`, but only with kernel >= 3.6.

You will have to do:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080
```

`ip_forward` is not necessary, because the packet is not forwarded, but if you don't include the sysctl for `route_localnet` (which works only in kernels >= 3.6), the packet will be dropped by the kernel because it considers it a "martian", coming from the outside and having a destination address of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yup, that works

Comment: Did not know about route_localnet. So old school and couldn't figure out why ip_forward wasnt working (suspected it wasn't needed but tried anyway).

Comment: Make sure you save `net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` otherwise it won't be persistent and after reboot the variable will go back to 0, causing the packet dropped. Then it would be very hard to figure why now everything is not working... it happened to me. ;)

Comment: Sorry to necro an old question but is there an ipv6 equivalent of `net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet` for use with `ip6tables`?

Comment: amazing. ive spent 4 hours until find it

Answer (score 0):

Reading the debian documentation (maybe works for other distros) I used this to redirect podman/docker ports to localhost:

> 8080 -> 80
>
> 8083 -> 443

```
#!/bin/bash

# reset iptables rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# redirect ports
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --src 0/0 --dst 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --src 0/0 --dst 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8083
```

check it:

```
curl -k https://localhost
curl https://localhost
```

https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls-local-port-redirection